# In Scala, how to serialize a single abstract method interface that carries an outer object that cannot be serialized?

Tags: scala, serialization, type-coercion, single-abstract-method

In Scala 2/3, if a trait is defined with a single abstract method:

```
  trait In
  trait Out

  trait FnBase {

    def apply(arg: In): Out
  }
```

any function with identical in/out signature will be coerced into an ad-hoc class that inherit this trait, this coercion has higher priority than any implicit conversion, e.g.:

```
trait NonSerializable {
  val v1 : FnBase = _ => new Out {}
// automatically becomes
  val v2 : FnBase = new FnBase {def apply(v: In): Out = new Out {}}
}
```

This is problematic as the serialized form of v2 will now carry NonSerializable as an outer reference, and trigger a NotSerializableException when being serialized.

This behaviour cannot be changed because:

- single abstract method interface already has the highest priority
- outer reference cannot be marked as `@transient`, and will always be included in serialized form

I'd like to disable this behaviour, what's the easiest way to do so?

Comment: What outer reference are you referring to? I don't see any in your code. And what's the bigger context: Spark, maybe?

Comment: yes, Spark, if you tried to serialise v1 or v2, you'll see that the entire NonSerializable be included

Comment: Yes but there's nothing preventing you to move these to a serializable `object` then. Is there? I mean: it's not a specific issue with SAM, it's the fact that you use `trait NonSerializable`.

Comment: in many cases, NonSerializable is an essential interface (e.g. scalatest AnyFunSpec) that should be discarded on serializing

Comment: BTW, I can't find any Scala doc or specification explaining the single abstract method interface, is it considered a backdoor?

Comment: @tribbloid https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#sam-conversion https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#sam-conversion-precedes-implicits