# All partial unification algorithms failed on implicit conversion from functions - How to improve in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit, unification, scala-2.13

Here is a simple example:

```scala
object UnificationOnConversionFromFn {

  trait :=>[I, R]

  implicit def fromVanilla[I, R](
      vanilla: I => R
  ): I :=> R = ??? // fail

  implicit def fromVanilla2[I, R, F <: I => R](
      vanilla: F
  ): I :=> R = ??? // fail

  implicit def fromVanilla3[I, R, F[A, B] <: A => B](
      vanilla: F[I, R]
  ): I :=> R = ??? // fail

  lazy val _fn0: Int :=> Int = {

    val a: Int :=> Int = fromVanilla { v =>
      v + 1
    }

    val b: Int :=> Int = { v =>
      v + 1
    }

    b
  }
}
```

despite the fact that any implicit function can be used to make it compile, they all failed:

```
UnifyingConversionFromFn.scala:27:28: missing parameter type
```

How to make any of them work? Any measure (except rewritng the code) is acceptable - macros, compiler options, compiler plugins, experimental compilers, you name it.

This is merely a simple case in compiler type unification, it shouldn't take artificial super-intelligence to solve

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/W4JJcTYbToGEBzOWZphk0Q/1

Comment: thanks a lot but this is not what I asked, (x: Int) is already defined before and is redundant

Comment: Is not defined before really, and this has nothing to do with partial unification. Is just type inference, and the language is designed in a way that the expression `x => x + 1` won't infer the type of `x` unless it knows the return type. And here it doesn't, because implicit conversions don't work backward.

Comment: _"Any measure (except rewritng the code) is acceptable"_ - why is getting rid of implicit conversions not acceptable in 2024? Haven't they been considered harmful anti-pattern since 2014?

_"macros, compiler options, compiler plugins, experimental compilers"_ - why would this be the lesser evil compared to writing simple, straightforward, idiomatic code?

Comment: If a function can be converted into `trait :=>[I, R]` doesn't that mean that this trait in practice is most likely a Single Abstract Method? [SAM syntax would eliminate the need for implicit conversion most of the time](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pxSWTShLQ9aHbhsgQ9FTKA), and the remaining cases could be handled with some explicit conversion.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok good point, my previous question is about SAM which turns out to be not friendly to serialization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77925091/in-scala-how-to-serialize-a-single-abstract-method-interface-that-carries-an-ou

Comment: IMHO your issue is not SAM but the fact that SAM creates non-serializable type. You would have the same problem if you implicitly converted into such type - how else you want to create an instance with nothing bad in closure, if not by putting the lambda in closure as well? AFAIK the only way of avoiding such things was invented in Spark which was using macros to rewrite closures in compile time into something that can be serializable. I heard of same idea in Scala 3 but I am not aware if anyone did it.